# react js Chat reorder message

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, chat

I have this code:

```
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="bg-white-900 p-10 border">       
          <ul className="h-80 overflow-y-auto flex flex-col">
            {messages.map((message, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                className={"flex flex-row w-full" + message.from === userA ? "justify-start" : "justify-end"}
              >
                <div className={`my-2 p-2 table text-sm rounded-md text-black ${
                  message.from === userA? "bg-slate-300 ml-auto" : "bg-slate-100"
                }`}
                >
                  {message.body}
                </div>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>

          <input
            name="message"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje..."
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            className="border-2 border-zinc-500 p-2 w-full text-black"
            value={message}          
          />
        </form>
```

so I just want each message to be displayed from the end of the parent container, like this example:

[image]

so, I added `flex flex-col` to ul element, but don't work, what's wrong??
I'm using tailwind css

currently I'm getting this:

[image]

what can I do to fix it??

Comment: @john, to use items-end utility class, you need to use flex as well. i.e. "h-80 overflow-y-auto flex items-end"

Comment: don't work, if I add flex, all the message are shown in the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="bg-white-900 p-10 border">       
          <ul className="h-80 overflow-y-auto flex flex-col">
            {messages.map((message, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                className={"flex flex-row w-full" + message.from === userA ? "justify-start" : "justify-end}
              >
                <div className={`my-2 p-2 table text-sm rounded-md text-black ${
                  message.from === userA? "bg-slate-300" : "bg-slate-100"
                }`}
                >

                  {message.body}
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>

          <input
            name="message"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje..."
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            className="border-2 border-zinc-500 p-2 w-full text-black"
            value={message}          
          />
        </form>
```

Comment: bro! I updated it, look at the images, the order messages

Comment: I think order of messages in the array is wrong. Try messages.reverse().map or use flex-col-reverse class in ul

Comment: yes!!! it work!! I added ```flex-col-reverse```  thanks you!!! I'll give you a point